# not able to get value of a variable in json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

**Model**

```
public class AlldataPoints
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string phone {get;set;}
    public string phase {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetResults1()
{
    List<AlldataPoints> lst = (List<AlldataPoints>)Session["list"];
    return Json(new { data = lst }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Script**

```
function Pie() {
    $.get("GetResults1", function (abc) {
        var bac = abc;
        for (i = 0; i < bac.length; i++) {
            var hello = bac[0].phase;
        }
    });
}
```

As my list has 3 array objects, I want to access the value for phase of each object array and put it into variable hello but on running, hello is undefined.

Comment: you are returning a JSON string but you're not parsing it in javascript, hence you are trying to access some properties of a string,. you should instead parse the result using something like: `var bac = JSON.parse(abc);`. Also, keep in mind that an object will be parsed, you may first want to check if you are getting the results first (by doing console.log(abc); and, then, by doing the rest.

Comment: the data is getting stored in bac

Comment: I know, but you have to think about **what data** is being stored in bac. It's currently a string, and you need to convert it to an object first if you want to iterate through it and get its properties.

Comment: data is stores as array[n]

Comment: each index is shown as object

Comment: Can you tell us what `console.log(abc)` outputs?

Answer (score 2):

As [briosheje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275797/briosheje) mentionned in his comment, the problem may be in the data type. You controller returns a JSON String, and is directly used in your controller. You need to be sure that the **data that your Javascript gets** is some JSON.

You can use, as suggested, the `JSON.parse(yourstring)` function, which will make sure that you are actually iterating  over a JSON object. What is going on here is the following process:

- Your controller sends the Json String to your JavaScript.
- Your JavaScript gets the **string** in your `http` request : `$.get("GetResults1", function (abc)`
- It then passes the **string** to bac : `var bac = abc`
- You then try to iterate over a **string** : `for (i = 0; i < bac.length; i++)`
- You check for the value at index `0` of your `bac` variable (which is a String). As JavaScript is a non-typed language, it obeys and considers your variable as an array of characters. So, it checks for your first character.
- Then, it tries to access the `phase` field of your character, which does not exist (`undefined`) and stores it into `hello` : `var hello = bac[0].phase (= undefined`).

---

**EDIT** You may check as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object?rq=1), which covers your problem very well.

Comment: Well reasoned and explanatory answer.